# When I run the selenium IDE script on Jenkins, I am getting HTML suite exception

Tags: jenkins, selenium-ide

```
HTML suite exception seen:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox 3 could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''firefox.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this:
*firefox3 c:\blah\firefox.exe
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.BrowserLauncherFactory.createBrowserLauncher(BrowserLauncherFactory.java:195)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.BrowserLauncherFactory.getBrowserLauncher(BrowserLauncherFactory.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.getBrowserLauncher(HTMLLauncher.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:198)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.runHtmlSuite(SeleniumServer.java:640)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:305)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox 3 could not be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing ''firefox.exe'' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox 3 like this:
*firefox3 c:\blah\firefox.exe
    at org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.locators.CombinedFirefoxLocator.findBrowserLocationOrFail(CombinedFirefoxLocator.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.BrowserInstallationCache.locateBrowserInstallation(BrowserInstallationCache.java:46)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.<init>(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.BrowserLauncherFactory.createBrowserLauncher(BrowserLauncherFactory.java:184)
    ... 8 more
Publishing Selenium report...
ERROR: Publisher org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.seleniumhtmlreport.SeleniumHtmlReportPublisher aborted due to exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.seleniumhtmlreport.SeleniumHtmlReportPublisher.perform(SeleniumHtmlReportPublisher.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:685)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1757)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Firefox is installed in - C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox
I have added the path in the Environment variables "*firefox C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\" without quotes..

Selenium version used - selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar
Mozilla Firefox version - 30.0
OS - Windows 8.1

Comment: The `*firefox` part is unnecessary. Just make sure the path is there in the definition of `PATH`. You can check in a `cmd` window with `echo %PATH%`

Comment: Removed *firefox and currently the path is C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\ still no luck the error persists

Comment: Hopefully a Windows 8 expert will chime in. If it were Linux, you could run `which firefox` to find out the actual path to the executable.